# iPad Simulator Xcode 3.2.4 - Naming

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, naming-conventions, simulator

I am running my code in Xcode 3.2.4 setting iOS 3.2 with iPad simulator, but when simulator opens iPad simulator but it shows the name as iPhone simulator on the top.

As I have to submit screenshots this has created a mess. How to change the name?

Comment: You can always upgrade to xcode4.0.